# How to set some context variable for a user/connection

Tags: postgresql

I currently use Firebird SQL as the db backend of my shareware, would like to support also PG 9.3+.

In FB I use set/get_context to do this:

[set-context](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-set-context.html)

[get-context](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-get-context.html)

e.g. I would do this after a user logs in:

```
select rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'LANGUAGE_ID', %s) \
        from rdb$database" % appobj.loggedInUser.language.id
```

In some of my views I would then use:

```
... AND t.fk_language_id=rdb$get_context('USER_SESSION', 'LANGUAGE_ID')
```

I searched through PG doc and did some googling but didn't find a solution yet.

Would appreciate any tips.
Werner

Comment: If this is always **per session** (=connection), you could use a temporary table

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a session variables in custom schema:

```
postgres=# set myvars.language_id = 10;
SET
postgres=# show myvars.language_id;
 myvars.language_id 
--------------------
 10
(1 row)
```

or via functions (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html):

```
postgres=# select set_config('myvars.language_id', '20', false);
 set_config 
------------
 20
(1 row)

postgres=# select current_setting('myvars.language_id');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 20
(1 row)
```

Comment: That looks good, will give it a try when a have a moment and report back.

Comment: Doesn't this set the environment for an entire DB? Not just for the particular DB connection?

Comment: this setting is only for session

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28061244/223226) so `context()` function can be used as both, getter and setter,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION context(text, text default null)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$

    select case when $2 is null
        then current_setting($1)
        else set_config($1, $2, false)
    end
    ;
$function$
;
```

Usage:

```
-- set
select context('USER_SESSION.LANGUAGE_ID', 'lang id');
```

and later,

```
-- get
select context('USER_SESSION.LANGUAGE_ID');
```

Comment: There is an exception if retrieving value for a key which wasn't set before in the current session.