# PostgreSQL set session variable

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql, auditing

My app which connects to PostgreSQL DB using same credentials (db provider requirement...)
However I need to recognize what app user is connecting to DB (eg for udates auditing etc)

I wonder if there is any way I can set some variable (which life is limited to session only), which then I can somehow read via DDLs.

** EDIT **

Ive also did some experiments using application_name in conneciton string and putting there simple user login - but this is not most elegant way...

```
SET application_name TO 'user_login';
select current_setting('application_name');
```

Any idea how to archive that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66225214/223226

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't abuse [`application_name`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-APPLICATION-NAME), there are custom variables (["customized options"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html)) for that:

```
SET my.app_user = 'user_login';
SELECT current_setting('my.app_user');
```

See:

- [User defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)